# After a transaction of BTC, is it possible to change the amount of BTC?

Tags: transactions

Kindly Explain.

If I have been transferred 10 BTC, but the transaction has not been confirmed. is it possible to change the amount of BTC 10 to 15?

Answer (score 3):

> **is it possible to change the amount of BTC 10 to 15?**

I believe the Replace By Fee (RBF) mechanism requires that you use at least one of the same inputs. You can only use RBF if the original transaction explicitly allows RBF.

Without RBF, so far as I know, the best you can do is issue a second transaction that includes the same inputs and more; which spends the higher amount and which has a much higher fee. You can then *hope* that the higher-fee transaction  gets mined / confirmed first. This would cause the original transaction to remain unconfirmed.